# Block user input of several fields in FormType

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a formType that I use to add new users to the system. Now I want to reuse this formType to modify user profiles, but while I want to continue printing all fields, I just want to allow to edit someone of them depending on the permissions that the user has over the user that is modifiyng. 
Of course, I can use the readonly attribute in FormType, but this just puts a readonly tag in the HTML code, which is nothing more than an ornament. I can put the additions of these fields inside an "if" block that only do the addition of fields if the user has the appropriate permissions, but then the twig code turns dirty with code that simulate the entire form.
Is another way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that in the controller, just check the permissions in the `edit` action using a [`Voter`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters_data_permission.html) class

Also you have to create the `EDIT_*` permissions like `EDIT_USER_NEWS`, `EDIT_USER_ARTICLE` [...]

If the user has no `EDIT` permissions, just throw an AccessDeniedException() exception

```
// editAction()
$sc = $this->get('security.context');
if (false === $sc->isGranted('EDIT', $user)) {
    throw new AccessDeniedException('Nope you cant edit this!');
}
```

Now if the user has `EDIT` permissions just setup the form according to the user permission

```
$user = new User();

$disabled_fields = array(); // This can be a risk
if ($sc->isGranted('EDIT_USER_NEWS', $user)) {
    $disabled_fields = array('field3', 'field4');
}

if ($sc->isGranted('EDIT_USER_ARTICLE', $user)) {
    $disabled_fields = array('field1', 'field2');
}

$form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $user, array('fields' => $disabled_fields));
// ...
```

In the FormType, disable the fields according to the options given

```
// FormType
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
     if (isset($options['fields'])) {
       $builder->add('field1', null, array('disabled' => 
                                      isset($options['fields']['field1'])));
       // others fields...
     } else {
       // Show all the fields?
     }
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array('fields' => array()));
}
```

The `disabled` option will disable the field, means that the user can't edit it, even if the user delete the property in the HTML

Of course that there are many ways to handle this, but I have this way on my project